# How to capture URL from a webform without using token value?

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a Webform as a block. Set to show on a certain content type with a hidden field returning the token value `%get[q]` to let the admins know from which page the form was submitted from.

Unfortunately it has intermittent errors that I've not been able to duplicate. Is there a better way to capture the URL?

Answer (score 0):

What about [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)?

Comment: using - %server[REQUEST_URI] - helped some. the hidden element now comes in with the cleanURL and not the node number but the issue remains. it keeps coming up with - (domain)/file/ajax/submitted/(field name)/form-(and what looks like long string of random characters) @beth

Comment: That sounds like the webform token, which all secure forms should have. What are the errors with GET['q']?

Answer (score 0):

What about Drupal official way? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/current_path/7